# How to send data from controller to jsp in spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send data to jsp but its not working

```
public class LoginPageController extends SimpleFormController
{
   public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
       throws ServletException
   {
       Loginpage lcmd=(Loginpage)command;
       System.out.println("This is LOGIN PAGE");
       System.out.println(lcmd.getUserName());
       System.out.println(lcmd.getPassWord());
       request.setAttribute("MSG","Thank u"); //This code not doing anything.
       return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("Login.jlc"));
   }
}
```

Comment: What should i write to send data to j s p,i tryed setAttribut in controller and in j s p ${logical name} but it not working.

Comment: in controller request.setAttribute("MSG","THANK U");in j s p ${MSG}

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the `request` object, that will indeed do nothing.

What you want is add a variable to the **Model**. So here's how you can do it:

Instead of:

```
request.setAttribute("MSG","Thank u"); //This code not doing anything.
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("Login.jlc"));
```

Try this:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("MSG", "Thank u");
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("Login.jlc"), model); // <-- notice this
```

This will enable you to access that `"Thank u"` value through the expression `${model.MSG}` and others, if you add them to the `model` map.